# Box-sizing on Blackberry

Tags: css

I'm almost done with a project and now I'm facing a problem I don't know how to solve.
I did the whole css styling with the box-sizing: border-box (with ie6/7 polyfill) applied and it worked like a charme on every device I tested, until I picked up a blackberry. It doesn't support box-sizing (actually it does, but only from the very last version) and now all my layout is broken. Since the project is almost finished I don't want to go back and update every single stylesheet to not use that css rule. What do you think would be the best way to tackle this?

speaking about this:
http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion is that you could perform a [server-side detection of the BlackBerry browser](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862) and if the version detetcted doesn't support the `box-sizing` property just send to the client an overriding stylesheet on the cascade, containing all the necessary rules (with an higher specificity, of course) to correct the wrong style.

Otherwise, if this method still need too much work to fix, you could try to serve a non-strict doctype for that specific browser only and see what box-model is used by that browser. For sure it's a bit hacky method, but maybe this change could have some good impact and "straighten" your layout.